# Create dropdownlist with numbers 1 to 30 mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I need create dropdownlist with numbers 1 to 30 . and to transfer this number to another view, where I need to show it.
Thanks

View (Index)

```
@Html.BeginForm()
{
//this I need DropdownList with numbers from 1 to 30
<input type = "submit" >Enter/>
}

[HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SecondView");
        }
```

How I display number in "SecondView"?

Comment: Please look at the [help] particularly on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 6):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkExperienceTime, Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() }),new { placeholder= Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.WorkExperienceTime), @class = "form-control" } )
```

Comment: Try to also add some explanation for your code. Code only answers are not encouraged on SO.

Comment: Short and concise. I like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

**Controller**

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++)
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value =    i.ToString() });
ViewBag.list = list;
return View();
```

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("drp", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "Text", "Value"),  "Select")
   <input type="submit">
}
```